# xlC at AIX 6.1 cannot compile != between string iterator

Tags: c++, std, aix

It seems that xlC in AIX 6.1 cannot compile reverse_iterator. For example,

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool isNonZero(const char c) {
  return c != '0';
}

void test()   {
  std::string str;
  const std::string::const_reverse_iterator rit_non_zero = std::find_if(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), isNonZero);

  if( rit_non_zero != str.rbegin())
    {
      const std::string::size_type ofs = str.length() - std::distance<std::string::const_reverse_iterator>(str.rbegin(), rit_non_zero);
      str.erase(str.begin() + ofs, str.end());
    }
}
```

It complains that The call at

```
rit_non_zero != str.rbegin()
```

does not match any parameter list for "operator!=".

Comment: @OP Hi, exactly what is your question?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, My question is that I can compile the code in gcc, but xlC cannot compile it. I do not know if I miss any xlC compilation options or not.

Comment: You didn't specify the xlC compiler-options you used, nor the version of xlC. Nonetheless, I think there is nothing wrong with your xlC, it's simply C++ being itself.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy: I compiled the code with 'xlC main.cc' w/o other options. I did 'xlC -v', it only shows me the help with IBM (2010) shown on the top. How do I get the version of xlC? Thank you.

Comment: What does `xlC -qversion` say?

Comment: IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V11.1 (5724-X13) version: 11.01.0000.0006

Comment: You might try to upgrade to V12.1 or V13.1 or even to g++

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy. Unfortunately I cannot update xlC. I manually rewrote the above w/o using iterators.